# How to execute code after not receiving any data with socket time out in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am using a TCP socket to send and receive data. My logic is that if my server receives data (for example 0 value) then that ends fine. But if my server does not receive any data after I set a timeout of 10 sec for my socket to close then I want my value to be default 1. The server code I am trying is below:

```
import socket
TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
TCP_PORT = 5004

BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(10)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()

while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data:
        break
        datalist = list(data)
        print("payload: %s" % datalist)
        conn.send(data)  # echo
    else:
        datalist = 1
        print("default value: %s" % datalist)
```

But after 10 sec I am getting timeout error and failing to make the default datalist value 1.
Please advise. The purpose is that if it does not receive any data then it will set the value to 1

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/code.py", line 15, in <module>
    conn, addr = s.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 292, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: you have defined timeout for it, `s.settimeout(10)`. just remove this line, see what happens

Comment: Nothing happens. The socket is open to receive data. But I am not sending any. I just want the socket to close so that I can set my algorithm a value of 1. The purpose is that if it does not receive any data then it will set the value to 1

Comment: your code stuck in line `conn, addr = s.accept()` until some client connects to it. so the rest of your code won't run if you have no connected client. then after 10 seconds you will get this error. but if you have a connected client then you should put your code in the form `try: something \n except Exception as e: some other things` as suggested in the answer by @Amk432.

Comment: actually, my code should be like: it should have the option to connect to a client and if it does not receive anything from the client then it will make the value 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set time out for the client, so if it send a message in ten second it should stay connected otherwise disconnect. it that is the case:

here is`server.py` code:

```
import socket
TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
TCP_PORT = 5004
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.settimeout(10)
data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
if data:
    conn.settimeout(None)
    conn.send(b"welcome")
    print("client is active")
    try:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)       
            if data:
                print("here is the message:",data)
            else:
                conn.close()
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print("error is",e)
else:
    print("client is inactive")
```

and here is your `client.py` code:

```
import socket
TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
TCP_PORT = 5004
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
x = input("write anything if you want to connect >")
s.send(bytes(x,'utf-8'))
data = s.recv(1024)
print(data)
try:
    while True:
        x = input("write your message >")
        s.send(bytes(x,'utf-8'))
except Exception as e:
    print("error is",e)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set timeout for socket then you have to handle time out exception, in this case what should happen after 10 seconds is over

```
while 1:
    try:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        if data:
            #data recieved
            datalist = list(data)
            print("payload: %s" % datalist)
            conn.send(data)  # echo
            break

    except socket.timeout:
            #10 seconds finished
            datalist = 1
            print("default value: %s" % datalist)
            break
```

Comment: actually, my code should be like: it should have the option to connect to a client and if it does not receive anything from the client then it will make the value 1 after a 10-sec timeout.